# How to add a key/value pair to a map of variants in cpp

Tags: c++, stdmap, variant, std-variant

Wanted to use a `std::map<std::string, std::variant<A, B>> my_map` where A and B are classes that have similar constructors (take a yaml object as argument), but I cannot figure out how to actually insert a key/value pair into such a map.

a similar minimum example

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int x): x_(x) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl;}
        int x_;
        void print() {std::cout << 2 * x_ << std::endl;}
};

class B {
    public:
        B (int x): x_(x) {std::cout << "B" << std::endl;}
        int x_;
        void print() {std::cout << 5* x_ << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    using var_t = std::variant<A, B>;
    std::map<std::string, var_t> my_map;
    var_t v {std::in_place_type<A>, 3};
    //my_map["a"] = v; // none of these work
    //my_map.emplace("a", v);// 
    my_map.insert({"a", v});
    std::visit([](auto&& var) { var.print();}, my_map["a"]);
}
```

Results in this

```
usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/tuple:2254:9: error: use of deleted function 'std::variant<_Types>::variant() [with _Types = {A, B}]'
 2254 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that the the variant types have ambiguous/non-default constructors so when it tries to build with the key "a" the compiler cannot figure out the correct constructor to use.

What's the correct way to use and add pairs to such a structure ?

Comment: You would need to add default ctors to your classes A and B: https://godbolt.org/z/cGxvz5azv

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Only `A` needs default constructor to use `operator[]`, but that's up to OP to say if default constructing `A` is the right choice. Perhaps forcing oneself to use `.at` and dealing with exceptions is correct in their use-case.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you are right, only the first class needs it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not with insertion, but with use of `operator[]`. This operator creates default-initialised object when key is not found in map, and your `std::variant` has no default constructor*.

Change

```
    std::visit([](auto&& var) { var.print();}, my_map["a"]);
```

to

```
    std::visit([](auto&& var) { var.print();}, my_map.at("a"));
```

and both of these initialisations will work:

```
    my_map.emplace("a", v);
    my_map.insert({"a", v});
```

---

* Variant only has default constructor if the first alternative can be default constructed. In your case, `A` has no default constructor, so `std::variant` will not be default-constructible.